# Convert TXT file to Json in Golang

Tags: json, go

I'm struggling trying to convert a text file to JSON.
I can't use python for limitations in the implementation so it needs to be in Go.

I have this file structure

```
VAULT_ADDR=https://address.com
SECRET_USERNAME={{tata/user}}
SECRET_PASSWORD={{tata/pass}}
SECRET_SLACK_TOKEN={{tata/token}}

SECRET_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID={{tata/space}}
SECRET_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN={{tata/stuff}}

SECRET_NEW_RELIC_TOKEN={{tata/tata}}
```

I'd need to covert it for a JSON structure, I tried a lot of things but don't know if I should use a structure, interface or how to do this.

would like to convert for this:

```
[  
{  
    "name":"VAULT_ADDR",
    "value":"https://address.com"
},
{  
    "name":"SECRET_USERNAME",
    "value":"{{tata/user}}"
},
{  
    "name":"SECRET_PASSWORD",
    "value":"{{tata/pass}}"
},
{  
    "name":"SECRET_SLACK_TOKEN",
    "value":"{{tata/token}}"
},
{  
    "name":"SECRET_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID",
    "value":"{{tata/space}}"
},
{  
    "name":"SECRET_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "value":"{{tata/stuff}}"
},
{  
    "name":"SECRET_NEW_RELIC_TOKEN",
    "value":"{{tata/tata}}"
}
]
```

this is my code so far...

```
package main

import (
  "flag"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "log"
  "os"
  "strings"
)

 var (
   file string
)

 func main() {

   flag.StringVar(&file, "f", "", "file path")
   flag.Parse()

   data, err := os.Open(file)
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer data.Close()

   file, err := ioutil.ReadAll(data)

   converter := string(file)

   s := strings.Split(converter, "=")

   for _, line := range s {
      parser := "name" + line

      fmt.Println(parser)
   }

 }
```

My code output:

```
name= VAULT_ADDR value
name= https://address.com
SECRET_USERNAME value
name= {{tata/user}}
SECRET_PASSWORD value
name= {{tata/pass}}
SECRET_SLACK_TOKEN value
name= {{tata/token}}

SECRET_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID value
name= {{tata/space}}
SECRET_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN value
name= {{tata/stuff}}

SECRET_NEW_RELIC_TOKEN value
name= {{tata/tata}} value
```

thank you

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement. Can you still explain what specific help you need? Are you stuck on how to parse the lines? Or on how to generate the JSON? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the data from a file as you do in your question and perform some extra validation and trimming on the strings and replace the template data with real. I am using fixed data to demonstrate how to do it.

Here is the example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Element struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    var data = `VAULT_ADDR = "https://address.com"
SECRET_USERNAME = "{{tata/user}}"
SECRET_PASSWORD = "{{tata/pass}}"
SECRET_SLACK_TOKEN = "{{tata/token}}"
SECRET_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID = "{{tata/space}}"
SECRET_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN = "{{tata/stuff}}"
SECRET_NEW_RELIC_TOKEN = "{{tata/tata}}"`

    var dataSlice = make([]Element, 0)
    lines := strings.Split(data, "\n")
    for _, line := range lines {
        keyVal := strings.Split(line, "=")
        dataSlice = append(dataSlice, Element{Name: keyVal[0], Value: keyVal[1]})
        // dataSlice[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1]
        // in real code make sure the dataSlice has length==2
    }
    bts, err := json.Marshal(dataSlice)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", bts)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked.
How can I mark your answer and the correct one?
thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a grey tick symbol under the votes. You can click it to become green https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow.